# CANDBC and ARXML difference

Tags: can-bus, autosar, automotive, pdu

What is the difference between CAN DBC and ARXML files

In some places people's uses DBC alone but in some places ARXML is used
I want to understand the concept ARXML over the DBC.
How autosar pdu MSG sent via ARXML ?
How can ig differs from pdu

Answer (score 0):

ARXML is the all-in-one exchange format of AUTOSAR consortium. By exchange I mean share of information between suppliers and manufacturers (and internally between desgin phases). So PDU's are not "*sent via ARXML*" but they are shared in the design phase of ECU networks. ARXML can contain a wide variety of informations; CAN network description is just a fraction of what it can hold.

CAN DBC is a format describing a CAN network and it is still used by smaller companies that can't afford or don't want to deal with AUTOSAR tooling. AUTOSAR is restricted to automotive field while CANDBC is not.

AUTOSAR toolchains that I've worked with all support the export and import of CAN network design between the file formats ARXML and CANDBC.

Comment: All the toolchains I worked with can import ARXML, but usually, they all have problems with certain messages (e.g. TimeSync is using a GeneralPurposePdu, DBC usually defines a multiplex message, Diag and XCP also get wrong).

Comment: @kesselhaus Do you think it's a limitation of the standard or just hard to implement properly so none of them bothered?

Comment: Sorry, I my comment is partly truncated in the middle. I meant, the tools have problems converting from DBC files to AUTOSAR ARXML, due to limitations in DBC format, e.g. DBC allows to map reception of messages only by mapping Rx-Signals. But XCP is not an ISignalIPdu but GeneralPurposePdu (category XCP), DiagReq/Res are DcmIPdus and require additionally NPdus mapped to CanFrame, TimeSync is not MultiplexedIPdu but GeneralPurposePdu (cat. GLOBAL_TIME).